# SSRS Report not showing graphs

Tags: reporting-services, graph, charts

I have a SSRS Report that suddenly dosen't show my graphs.

They show up in Visual Studio but not when uploaded to the Reporting Server

They worked a couple of weeks ago.

[image]

Comment: Found this [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1464818-150-1.aspx), will try it out tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by restarting the service, answer found here

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1464818-150-1.aspx